# Unable to check multiple if else condition in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I am trying to check some multiple conditions in JQuery but it doesn't return the desired result. whatever I input it always went to else condition.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#installment').on("keydown keyup", check);
  function check() {
    var inst = Number($("#installment").val());
    if (inst === 2 || inst === 4 || inst === 6 || inst === 12) {
      return true;
    } else {
      $("#installment").val('');
      alert("you can not set wrong value");
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>Number of Installment</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="installment" id="installment"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting and doesn’t happen?

Comment: If entering 12 doesn’t work, that’s because when entering the digit 1 you clear the input. With this type of approach you’ll only be able to validate 1 char input, or inputs where you add the entire prefixes. Another note, val returns a string and you are strict checking.

Comment: @RaduDiță "val returns a string" - that's why it has `Number()` around it

Comment: @freedomn-m My bad, missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the **`keydown` triggered before the `value` update**. So if you enter '2'. The value will return `''` And `Number('')` is `0` so it always go to `else`
Just remove the keydown event only use `keyup`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#installment').on("keyup", check);

  function check() {
    var inst = Number($("#installment").val());
    console.log(inst)
    if (inst === 2 || inst === 4 || inst === 6 || inst === 12) {
      return true;
    } else {
      $("#installment").val('');
      alert("you can not set wrong value");
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>Number of Installment</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="installment" id="installment"></td>
</tr>
```

As **@Radu Diță** mentioned in the comment that `12` can never be valid if `1` is not so to fix that you can use [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#installment').on("keyup", check);
  function check() {
    var inst = Number($("#installment").val());
    console.log(inst)
    if (inst === 2 || inst === 4 || inst === 6 || '12'.startsWith(String(inst))) {
      return true;
    } else {
      $("#installment").val('');
      alert("you can not set wrong value");
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>Number of Installment</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="installment" id="installment"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Or use `input` event to also pick up other input methods (just not `keydown` as detailed here)

Comment: Key up will not solve the entire problem. 12 will never be validated as 1 is not valid.

Comment: @Radu Diță I have attempted to fix that problem. Please see the edit. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Not much else you can do without a major change to how this works, but OP needs to be aware that there needs to be a secondary validation to ensure 1 doesn't pass on in the process (but should have this anyway as javascript shouldn't be the only validation, it's a UI-nicety / first-catch only)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `keydown` event fires before the value of the input is modified. Use `keyup` (or better yet, `input`) instead:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#installment').on("input", check);

  function check() {
    var inst = parseInt($("#installment").val());
    if (inst == 2 || inst == 4 || inst == 6 || inst == 12) {
      return true;
    } else {
      $("#installment").val('');
      alert("you can not set wrong value");
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>Number of Installment</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="installment" id="installment"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: But required if `12` should be allowed as a valid answer @freedomn-m.

Comment: OK then @freedomn-m I'll remove that.

Comment: TBH, in this case, I'm not sure what else can be done with OPs limit code (so I've removed my previous comments) - it would need to have a secondary validation to ensure 1 doesn't pass on in the process (but should have this anyway as javascript shouldn't be the only validation, it's a UI-nicety / first-catch only)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#installment').on("keydown keyup", check);
  function check(event) {
    var inst = $(this).val();
    if (inst === "") {
        return;
    }
    if (inst == 2 || inst == 4 || inst == 6 || inst == 12) {
      return true;
    } else {
      $("#installment").val('');
      alert("you can not set wrong value");
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>Number of Installment</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="installment" id="installment"></td>
</tr>
```

In this code `if` starts working but only for `2`, `4` and `6`. It will not work for `12` as the first input is `1` which you doesn't validate instead of validating the input in keydown and keyup try to use `blur` once user finish writing something then validation works as you you like to.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#installment').on("blur", check);
  function check(event) {
    var inst = Number($(this).val());
    if (inst === 2 || inst === 4 || inst === 6 || inst === 12) {
      return true;
    } else {
      $("#installment").val('');
      alert("you can not set wrong value");
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>Number of Installment</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="installment" id="installment"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    var val = $("#installment").val();
  $('#installment').on("keydown keyup",
  function () {
    var inst = Number($("#installment").val());
    if (inst === 2 || inst === 4 || inst === 6 || inst === 12) {
      alert("OK");
     return false;
    } else {
      $("#installment").val('');
      alert("you can not set wrong value");
      //return false;
    }
  });
});
```